# Can I convert 2 two-pole 60A breakers into 3 two-pole 40A breakers

Tags: circuit-breaker, subpanel, tankless

Considering a new electric tankless water heater.  But my 18yr old existing subpanel doesn't match what most new heaters use.

Any help on the best way to go about this would be great.

TIA[image: Main panel]

[image: sub panel and old heater]

[image: Murray sub panel]

UPDATE:
Finding the quad breaker was tough, there's a shortage of supply these days, but finally got one.
Spent 9hrs yesterday, including 3 trips to HD, and it works! Changing the breakers was easy.  Striping the wires was the hardest part of the electrical work.
Thanks for everyone's help here.  Added an after picture below.
Total cost for electrical was about $100.  $60 for breakers ($44+$15), $25 of 8/2 wire, $15 for clamps and tape.  The heater cost me $650 plus $50 for isolation valves. Entire project was under $1000.

[image: after]

Comment: A better explanation is really needed. No 2P60's are present, and it seems like you already have 125A feeding a water heater. For capacity reasons we need to know is that staying, being replaced?

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear.  Those are not 2P60s connected next to my heater?  I believe I have enough current capacity, but I need three 40A breakers instead of two 60A.  Because they are 240v, I thought they were 2P.

Comment: I may have mis read part of the question but increasing the load on this service still looks to be beyond load calculations.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I might not have been clear enough on my intention. I want to replace my faulty tankless heater with a unit that pulls no more current. But newer models require 3 2P40's instead of the 2 2P60's that my existing set up has.  So no change to the main panel, was my assumption if there was a way to convert near the water heater.  Sounds like there are some options to do this.  I know nothing though.  Open to reconsidering if there are more details to consider.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Well designed, mostly.

So what we're looking at here is a commercial 120A tankless heater *with its cover removed*, and next to it, a Siemens 4-space subpanel.  All in a custom equipment bay that's been drywalled.  I'd guess a cabinet door swings over this? Well done.

The good news is, "the last guy" really did this right *in the large sense*, bringing a single 125A feeder from your main panel to this subpanel.   It only takes 2 breaker spaces in your main panel, and it means you can fit any of  the 120A-class water heaters here, whether they take 2, 3 or 4 circuits to power them.

The bad news is, "the last guy" *in the small sense* did did *exactly the thing we constantly warn people about*: using a subpanel that is barely enough for immediate needs and provides no room for future expansion.  Now, since the water heater accounts for 96% of the panel's capacity, there isn't really any *room* to hold anything else, but gosh, the price difference to a 6-space panel *wasn't even a latté* and would have protected the case of a 3-circuit water heater, as many are made.

### But it's still good.

While this usually doesn't work anymore, *in this particular case* we can fall back on the trick of using "double-stuff" breakers.  This panel is a dead-ringer for a Siemens/Murray E0408xx1125 panel, so assuming it's a Siemens...

Siemens does indeed make a breaker that crams two 40A/240V breakers into 2 spaces, the [Q24040CT2](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Siemens-Two-40-Amp-Double-Pole-Type-QT-Quad-Circuit-Breaker-Q24040CT2/206632164).  And indeed, the outer poles have common trip.

[image]

This bad-boy goes in one of the double breakers spaces.  A run-of-the-mill Siemens 40A breaker ($10) goes in the other. You now have three 40A circuits.

Remember, just as the handle-ties suggests, one of the circuits goes on the *inner* screws, and the other circuit goes in the *outer*.  Very important!

### You need to mark the wires! (the last guy didn't)

Wire needs to be #8 copper or larger.  #6 aluminum will also work.  **White wires need to be re-marked with tape because they'll be used as hot wires**. Black will do, but for style points --

-- actually, hold on.  There isn't *really* a need or purpose to distinguish the two hot wires **from each other**.  However it is absolutely vital to distinguish them **by circuit**.  So I recommend re-coloring *both* black *and* whites in each cable, making the same color in each cable.   E.G.

- Cable 1 becomes yellow, yellow, ground*
- Cable 2 becomes blue, blue, ground
- Cable 3 becomes red, red, ground.

They sell a 5-pack of colored electrical tape for like $4. This will assure a "pro looking" installation, and make it very easy for you to keep the circuits straight.

---

* Black-black-ground is also fine here, but I figure if you don't own any black electrical tape, you can get by with just the 5-color pack :)

Comment: Harper, thank you!  Seriously impressed with the activity on this site.  That goes for all of the replies.  So if it's not a Siemans panel, should I buy one?  I will definitely follow your recommendations on marking each set of wires. Totally worth the few bucks.  And the 'last guy' who worked on this also decided I didn't need isolation valves to maintain the heater, so he clearly wasn't looking out for the next guy.

Comment: Oh and you are right about the cabinet doors and heater with outer shell removed.  It's cute but I would have built a larger cabinet for future expansion

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, what color should the ground wire be?  Noob question for sure...

Comment: @buddylee whatever panel it is, that same company will make a 40/40 quadplex for it.    It may be a Murray - that's Siemens.  So is ITE.  Grounds are always bare, green, or yellow with a green stripe.  You're not allowed to remark them anyway.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks again!

Comment: It is a Murray.  And I see the bare ground wires.  And I see the wires are 8 gauge with 10 guage ground.  I'll add an image in case it helps anyone else

Comment: Yeah, it's the Siemens-era Murray version of the panel Harper mentioned, so you're good to use the QT breaker he posted in his answer, as per [this letter from Siemens](https://www.downloads.siemens.com/download-center/Download.aspx?pos=download&fct=getasset&id1=BTLV_65887)

Comment: Perfect! I ordered the breakers and some 8/2 wire.  I'll post an after picture once I getter done.

Comment: If 2 of those are 6/2 wire, you are welcome to continue those in service.  You don't *have* to downgride wire sizes.

Comment: Makes sense, less current density is not a bad thing. They are 8/2 though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems the 125A feeds the 4 space panel with 60A breakers, and you are replacing the existing water heater.

It doesn't appear that Schneider makes a double tandem 2P40 to squeeze two 2P40's into two 1" spaces, and without panel label we can't tell if tandems are allowed/blocked from fitting.

A new 6 or 8 space replacement panel is about $35 on Amazon, so that's not incredibly expensive.

Comment: Thanks NoSparksPlease, and no smoke either. :).  Yes, that's what I would like to do.  Would the panel label be under the grey cover?  I could take another picture if it helps.  But I think you are saying I could just look for a 6 space replacement panel.  Thanks for your input and patience.

Comment: Schneider opposes *the very principle* of UL-Classified breakers (approving brand X breaker in brand Y panel). Their real motivation is that they overcharge for QO breakers and want that monopoly protected, but to "walk their talk" they absolutely refuse to make a variant of HOM that is UL-classified for MP, Q, BR etc.  As such, Schneider is only for Schneider.

Comment: I misidentified the brand of panel, didn't intend to recommend a classified solution. Despite recognition I don't have confidence in classifieds, and don't recommend as a primary option. My lack of confidence may be misplaced due to my experiences with awful local distributor of Eaton products and receiving many misconfigured products from them.